# Why is helm-recentf not fuzzy?

Tags: init-file, helm

For some reason, fuzzy matching is not working in `helm-recentf` for me (though it is working everywhere else).

I have the following settings in my .emacs file:

```lisp
(setq helm-recentf-fuzzy-match t
      helm-buffers-fuzzy-matching t
      helm-completion-in-region-fuzzy-match t
      helm-mode-fuzzy-match t)
```

I assume that there is some overlap with the functionality of these settings, but I don't see why any of them should mess up `helm-recentf-fuzzy-match`. Also, I have tried setting only `helm-recentf-fuzzy-match` to `t` and removed the other settings, and still no good. Also, when I check the value for `helm-recentf-fuzzy-match` this is what I get:

`` helm-recentf-fuzzy-match is a variable defined in `helm-files.el'.
Its value is t
Original value was nil ``

Am I experiencing a bug, or is there something I need to configure/have configured wrong? Thank you!

## Update and details:

I am using **Emacs 24.5** and **Helm 20150704.1247**.

I tried loading up emacs without my init, and only turning on helm mode with fuzzy matching for recentf, and it still doesn't work. On top of that, if I use `helm-mini` I have fuzzy matching in the `Buffers` section, but not the `Recentf` section...

Comment: It's working for me. What helm are you using? What Emacs version? Can you bisect your init?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem as you: looking at the source for the variable definition it looks like the form he is using to declare it is not valid in Emacs 24 any more:

```
(defcustom helm-recentf-fuzzy-match nil
"Enable fuzzy matching in `helm-source-recentf' when non--nil."
  :group 'helm-files
  :type 'boolean
  :set (lambda (var val)
     (set var val)
     (setq helm-source-recentf
           (helm-make-source "Recentf" 'helm-recentf-source
             :fuzzy-match helm-recentf-fuzzy-match))))
```

Specifically the `:set` keyword doesn't seem to be valid so the lambda that redefines the source is never called.

To workaround this I just redeclared the source manually in my `init.el` file and it worked fine.

```
;; helm-recentf-fuzzy-match var is broken: redeclare it manually
(setq helm-source-recentf 
  (helm-make-source "Recentf" 'helm-recentf-source
    :fuzzy-match t))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is still the only way to make helm-recentf working, at least for me.